# Implement maze generation algorithm in Javascript

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, maze

I understand the "Depth-First" maze geerating algorithm but I need a little help implementing it with Javascript.

Comment: A little? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your question is way too vague and lacking information to get any form of help. Please edit and add some more information like which parts specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Maze Generation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#JavaScript) at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org) contains many implementations to generate and show a maze, using the simple Depth-first search algorithm:

Code in JavaScript:

```
function maze(x,y) {
    var n=x*y-1;
    if (n<0) {alert("illegal maze dimensions");return;}
    var horiz=[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) horiz[j]= [];
    var verti=[]; for (var j= 0; j<y+1; j++) verti[j]= [];
    var here= [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)];
    var path= [here];
    var unvisited= [];
    for (var j= 0; j<x+2; j++) {
        unvisited[j]= [];
        for (var k= 0; k<y+1; k++)
            unvisited[j].push(j>0 && j<x+1 && k>0 && (j != here[0]+1 || k != here[1]+1));
    }
    while (0<n) {
        var potential= [[here[0]+1, here[1]], [here[0],here[1]+1],
            [here[0]-1, here[1]], [here[0],here[1]-1]];
        var neighbors= [];
        for (var j= 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (unvisited[potential[j][0]+1][potential[j][1]+1])
                neighbors.push(potential[j]);
        if (neighbors.length) {
            n= n-1;
            next= neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random()*neighbors.length)];
            unvisited[next[0]+1][next[1]+1]= false;
            if (next[0] == here[0])
                horiz[next[0]][(next[1]+here[1]-1)/2]= true;
            else 
                verti[(next[0]+here[0]-1)/2][next[1]]= true;
            path.push(here= next);
        } else 
            here= path.pop();
    }
    return ({x: x, y: y, horiz: horiz, verti: verti});
}

function display(m) {
    var text= [];
    for (var j= 0; j<m.x*2+1; j++) {
        var line= [];
        if (0 == j%2)
            for (var k=0; k<m.y*4+1; k++)
                if (0 == k%4) 
                    line[k]= '+';
                else
                    if (j>0 && m.verti[j/2-1][Math.floor(k/4)])
                        line[k]= ' ';
                    else
                        line[k]= '-';
        else
            for (var k=0; k<m.y*4+1; k++)
                if (0 == k%4)
                    if (k>0 && m.horiz[(j-1)/2][k/4-1])
                        line[k]= ' ';
                    else
                        line[k]= '|';
                else
                    line[k]= ' ';
        if (0 == j) line[1]= line[2]= line[3]= ' ';
        if (m.x*2-1 == j) line[4*m.y]= ' ';
        text.push(line.join('')+'\r\n');
    }
    return text.join('');
}
```

Code in Java:

```
public int[][] generateMaze() {
    int[][] maze = new int[height][width];
    // Initialize
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j &lt; width; j++)
            maze[i][j] = 1;

     Random rand = new Random();
     // r for row、c for column
     // Generate random r
     int r = rand.nextInt(height);
     while (r % 2 == 0) {
         r = rand.nextInt(height);
     }
     // Generate random c
     int c = rand.nextInt(width);
     while (c % 2 == 0) {
         c = rand.nextInt(width);
     }
     // Starting cell
     maze[r][c] = 0;

     //　Allocate the maze with recursive method
     recursion(r, c);

     return maze;
 }

 public void recursion(int r, int c) {
     // 4 random directions
     int[] randDirs = generateRandomDirections();
     // Examine each direction
     for (int i = 0; i &lt; randDirs.length; i++) {

         switch(randDirs[i]){
         case 1: // Up
             //　Whether 2 cells up is out or not
             if (r - 2 &lt;= 0)
                 continue;
             if (maze[r - 2][c] != 0) {
                 maze[r-2][c] = 0;
                 maze[r-1][c] = 0;
                 recursion(r - 2, c);
             }
             break;
         case 2: // Right
             // Whether 2 cells to the right is out or not
             if (c + 2 &gt;= width - 1)
                 continue;
             if (maze[r][c + 2] != 0) {
                 maze[r][c + 2] = 0;
                 maze[r][c + 1] = 0;
                 recursion(r, c + 2);
             }
             break;
         case 3: // Down
             // Whether 2 cells down is out or not
             if (r + 2 &gt;= height - 1)
                 continue;
             if (maze[r + 2][c] != 0) {
                 maze[r+2][c] = 0;
                 maze[r+1][c] = 0;
                 recursion(r + 2, c);
             }
             break;
         case 4: // Left
             // Whether 2 cells to the left is out or not
             if (c - 2 &lt;= 0)
                 continue;
             if (maze[r][c - 2] != 0) {
                 maze[r][c - 2] = 0;
                 maze[r][c - 1] = 0;
                 recursion(r, c - 2);
             }
             break;
         }
     }

 }

 /**
 * Generate an array with random directions 1-4
 * @return Array containing 4 directions in random order
 */
 public Integer[] generateRandomDirections() {
      ArrayList<Integer> randoms = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           randoms.add(i + 1);
      Collections.shuffle(randoms);

     return randoms.toArray(new Integer[4]);
 }
```

[Source, demo and some more explanations](http://www.migapro.com/depth-first-search)